# Firebase Dynamic Links -> universal links only for sub paths

Tags: firebase-hosting, firebase-dynamic-links

My website is hosted in Firebase without problems.
I also have an matching iOS app that is successfully using Firebase dynamic links (added keys to plist file, entitlements...) with configured universal links (via Firebase) to this website. I have setup this custom domain for the dynamic links also. Works beautifully but...

Firebase correctly generates the [apple-app-site-association file](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/inter-process_communication/allowing_apps_and_websites_to_link_to_your_content/enabling_universal_links) (in my hosted website) :

```
{
    "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": [{
            "appID": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "paths": ["NOT /_/*", "/*"]
        }]
    }
}
```

But this matches my whole website -> there are not paths defined.

I would only like to match universal links of format `mydomain.com/link how` can I do this?

How can I tell Firebase to generate a different apple-app-site-association file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have been in contact with Firebase support and for the moment the AASA file is always generated as shown in the question = for the full site. A change request has been filed :-)

As a work around:

- disable the automatic generation of the AASA, by setting `appAssociation` field in your project's firebase.json file to `NONE`.
- Then manually create the AASA-file and upload it (usual way via Firebase hosting).

Comment: Just to verify one more time, this custom AASA file should be hosted at our domain, not in firebase. Right?

Comment: is it necessary to host our website on firebase hosting as we already have hosting server?

Answer (score 0):

While it is not possible to customize the AASA easily here is another workaround that may be applicable if you do not need non-matching links to work:

Keep the file as is, but set the `Allowlist URL pattern` in dynamic links. Here you can prevent firebase from allowing targets that do not match your defined patterns from the allow list. Technically, the AASA still allows it, but firebase will block the link (it will show an error).

Find more in the firebase docs: https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9021429

Note that this also **disables all other platforms from using the non-matching links**.